# How do I make Web App reference WCF service stored in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, azure

I have a deployed a web app to azure. The web app used a WCF service that was stored on my computer but I have now also moved the WCF service to azure and is now part of the web app, I followed Task 3 Exercise 2: Deploying to Windows Azure Web Sites in this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2014/03/31/moving-a-wcf-service-and-database-to-the-cloud.aspx. My problem is that the web app still references the WCF service on my computer instead of the one in azure and I'm not sure how to change it.

I tried going into webmatrix to change my .cs files but you cant do that within webmatrix. How could I change the code to reference the WCF stored in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how I didnt realise this before but I just added a new service reference to my website. The url of the service was the url of the new webserivce that I hosted with Azure.